Is there a format pattern for DecimalFormat to have positive and negative signs in front of numbers except for 0?
I am using a format to show signs in my kotlin/Java project and the format is doing exactly what it should having poisitive signs in front of positive numbers and negative sign in front of negative numbers.
However the zero have a positive sign which is my problem, i want no signs in front of 0.
This code shows for Exemple +1 +2 +3 ... -1 -2 -3.. and for zero it has the positive sign +0.
I want the zero to have no sign.
private companion object {
        const val DECIMAL_SIGN_FORMAT = "+#;-#"
    }

private val numberSignFormatter = DecimalFormat(DECIMAL_SIGN_FORMAT)

numberSignFormatter.format(progress).toString()


I think you will probably just have to add special handling to your code for the number 0 (zero).

That's what i was afraid of.

If progress (the number you want to format) is a float or double, then there is a difference between +0.0 and -0.0, and DecimalFormat shows you which one it is.

I don't think this can be directly done with any of Java APIs (or Kotlin, for that matter, that just provides wrappers around the Java API).
You can always define your own function that regularly formats the number and then removes the +.
A simple version could look like this:
inline fun String.formatZeroWithoutSign(number: Number): String =
    format(number).replace("+0", "0")

You can use it like this (or choose any other format you like):
"%1$+d".formatZeroWithoutSign(progress)

I chose the printf-style formatter since it is a bit easier to use, but this can obviously also be done with DecimalFormat if you want to stick to that.
As also noted in the comments, this may not produce accurate results in all situtaions. A more narrow approach would be more reboust:
inline fun String.formatZeroAs0(number: Number): String =
    if (number == 0) "0"
    else format(number)

With this you can only format a single number at a time, but its behavior is more predictible: It will format the number with the given pattern unless 0 is provided, then it will bypass all formatting and just output "0".
As an aside, if you're on Android the Android SDK provides a NumberFormatter that has this built-in:
NumberFormatter
    .withLocale(...)
    .sign(SignDisplay.EXCEPT_ZERO)
    .format(progress)


.replace("+0", "0") doesn't seem like a good choice, because it will affect "+0.1". I got the impression it was only zero itself which should have no sign, i.e. "+0.1", "0", "-0.1". I'd just do if (formatted.equals("+0")) return "0"

Yeah, this may also produce incorrect results in some other edge cases where a + can occur somewhere else in the output (with multiple numbers or some other format pattern). It all depends on how robust it must be. I edited my answer to make this more clear and provided a more robust alternative.

@Michael: if (formatted.equals("+0")) return "0" also won't work if the pattern contains more than just the simple number formatting, which might also be unexpected behavior.

if (number == 0) doesn't compile. A Number is not compatible with int. You can probably (sometimes) get away with doing if (number.doubleValue() == 0.0).
